# Which story contains a planet named something like Istinigishinoburilahaha?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, zoo

As a kid, I read a story about a husband and wife lizard people.  They arrived by spaceship as passengers or colonists.  I remember the wife complaining that the owners had made the temperature in the ship too cold for lizard people like them when they woke.  Whatever they were expecting, I think they wound-up in a zoo.  They came from a planet with the amazing name of Istiniogishinoburilahaha (of course I can't remember the spelling but I remember the way rolled off your tongue if you said it out loud).

Comment: Sounds almost Entish.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - I think you mean Welsh

Comment: Well, they both have a pleasant lilt.

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like the short story "The Underprivileged" by Brian Aldiss.

A paragraph about the story from [Aldiss's website](https://brianaldiss.co.uk/about/the-critics/the-inhumanity-of-brian-w-aldiss/)

> In “The Underprivileged,” the human Others are Saton and Corbis, reptilian descendants of the human race. They find themselves relocated, and Saton turns to Corbis: “The beautiful yellow pupils of her eyes had contracted to slits in fear. As he looked at her, loving her, the fear suddenly enveloped him too. **He was overcome by the distrust the Istinogurzibeshilahans had for the races of humanity they called Warms.** It was the distrust the underprivileged feel for those who have the advantages, and because it was instinctive, it went deep” (41). Corbis says, ” ‘I feel that we are despised as an inferior species of man’ ” (47-48). The fear is not unfounded; the story ends in horror when Saton and Corbis realize they have been given an injection unawares that makes them always happy. Their human guide, asked if he has the injection too, says, ” ‘Certainly. Only being resident, I don’t need as much as. . .as visitors. Only the very eminent are allowed to be creatively miserable’ ” (52).